# Definition of dx·dy in the Herschel-Maxwell derivation of Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I'm struggling to find the significance of $dx$ and $dy$ in terms of the [Herschel-Maxwell derivation](http://www-biba.inrialpes.fr/Jaynes/cc07s.pdf) of Normal Distribution.

My strongest theory so far is that $\rho(x,y)$ is a function which gives the probability of exactly the point $(x,y)$. Then $dx$ and $dy$ are multiplied, giving a small area around the function, and when multiplied by p, results in a probability density function. Therefore $\rho·dx·dy$ is the probability of a small area 'being selected' on the graph.

I invite clarification or confirmation of this theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: The Normal distribution is (absolutely) continuous. Hence, $\rho(x,y)$ cannot be the the probability of (x,y), since the probability of (x,y) is $0$.

Your basic intuition is pretty good, but not entirely correct. $\rho(x)dxdy$ is a *probability measure* that is defined by the *probability density function* $\rho$.
A measure is a function that maps certain sets (*measurable sets*) to positive values.
These sets are called *events* when speaking about probability.
To evaluate the measure $\rho(x)dxdy$ for a given event $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, one just needs to integrate:
$$\iint_A \rho(x)dxdy.$$